# Cannot navigate from modal to full screen with no bottom tab in React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have a bottom tab navigator with 2 icons of HomeScreen and MenuScreen, a separate screen (ProfileScreen), and a modal (ProfileLoginModal). The modal has a button that should redirect ProfileScreen. I put `navigation.navigate("ProfileScreen")` in the modal, but it's not doing anything, it's not even giving me an error.

But if I change it to one of the screens in the bottom tab nav, for example `navigation.navigate("Root", {screen: "HomeScreen})`, it works just fine. It just doesn't work with screens outside the bottom tab nav.

**NOTE:** I do not want a  bottom tab on ProfileScreen, so putting it in a nested navigation is not an option.

Can anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Navigation structure:

```
- BottomTabNavigator (Root)
   - HomeScreen
   - MenuScreen
- ProfileScreen
- ProfileLoginModal
```

Here is my navigation:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

<NavigationContainer linking={LinkingConfiguration}>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Root"
      component={BottomTabNavigator}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="ProfileScreen"        // ProfileScreen (destination)
      component={ProfileScreen}
    />
    <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ProfileLoginModal"    // Go to ProfileScreen from this modal
        component={ProfileLoginModal}
       />
    </Stack.Group>
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>


const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<RootTabParamList>();

function BottomTabNavigator() {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
      screenOptions={...}
    >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={...}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Menu"
        component={MenuScreen}
        options={...}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Typings:

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Root: NavigatorScreenParams<RootTabParamList> | undefined;
  ProfileScreen: undefined;
  ProfileLoginModal: undefined;
};

export type RootStackScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, Screen>;

export type RootTabParamList = {
  HomeScreen: undefined;
  MenuScreen: undefined;
};

export type RootTabScreenProps<Screen extends keyof RootTabParamList> =
  CompositeScreenProps<
    BottomTabScreenProps<RootTabParamList, Screen>,
    NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList>
  >;
```

I'm using React Native with Expo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
const HomeNavigator = () => {
   return(
     <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="HomeScreen"
      component={HomeScreen}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="ProfileScreen"        // ProfileScreen (destination)
      component={ProfileScreen}
    />
    <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="ProfileLoginModal"    // Go to ProfileScreen from this modal
        component={ProfileLoginModal}
       />
    </Stack.Group>
  </Stack.Navigator>)
}

function BottomTabNavigator() {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeNavigator"
      screenOptions={...}
    >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="HomeNavigator"
        component={HomeNavigator}
        options={...}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Menu"
        component={MenuScreen}
        options={...}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: As I said, I don't want a bottom tab navigator on ProfileScreen, so nesting navigation is not an option. Unless there's a way to hide the bottom tab?